# Twilio Twiml for voicemail forwarding

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I'm attempting to use Twiml to setup up the following workflow. Can anyone provide clarification on the parts I'm missing?

This is what I want to achieve:

1. Someone calls my Twilio number
2. Dial up to 10 numbers simultaneously
3. If no one picks up send the user to voicemail
4. Send voicemail email to multiple email addresses

If the call is connected

5. Whisper message for receiver
6. Record the phone call
7. Track city & state of caller
8. Send SMS to me when someone calls

This is what I have so far:

```html
<Response>
  <Play> URL of mp3 greeting optional </Play>
  <Dial record="true">
    <Number>
      +18589876543
    </Number>
    <Number>
      +4151234567
    </Number>
    <Number>
      +6197654321
    </Number>
    <Number>
      +18589876543
    </Number>
    <Number>
      +18589876543
    </Number>
  </Dial>
  <Sms to="+6197654321">
    Congrats! You have just received a phone call on your Texas phone line 
  </Sms>
</Response>
```

Any help at all is appreciated.

Comment: OK after watching these videos https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X9uH53HE5Fk&t=1s https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CeJxlDRP1CQ I have come up with this:

Comment: Hi, you have the simultaneous dial and recording the answered call so far. What have you tried with respect to the rest? Are you working in a particular programming language? Are you getting errors?